# How do I know if automapper has already been initialized?

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way to know if automapper has already been initialized?
For example:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.IsInitialized(); // would return false
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize( /*options here*/ );
AutoMapper.Mapper.IsInitialized(); // would return true
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue because I must call `Mapper.Initialize` in every single unit test. But the tests all fail except the first one.  Calling `Mapper.Reset` does not help.  I guess the only solution is to hack up some global variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

It throws `System.InvalidOperationException...Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration.`.

Comment: decent hack. Thanks! =)

Comment: It now throws an AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException

Comment: @Hypenate, does it show more information about exception? Are you sure you put all mappings in your automapper configuration correctly?

Comment: I'm seeing an InvalidOperationException when the mapper isn't initialized. Otherwise an AutoMapperConfigurationException is thrown for "unmapped members were found".  So for this to work, you need to ignore the latter exception.

Answer (score 13):

You could call `Mapper.Reset();` before initializing your mapper. I do this when initializing my unit test classes:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitializer(TestContext context)
{
    Mapper.Reset();
    AutoMapperDataConfig.Configure();            
}
```

Comment: Seems to be the way to use it: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#resetting-static-mapping-configuration

Comment: @martinoss - It is not working for me. I rest the mapper before initializing but still, it throws an error like "Mapper already initialize".

Answer (score 1):

In our particular case, we had multiple unit tests competing for the same instance of AutoMapper. Even if we used the Reset() method, it threw the error that it was already initialized. We solved the problem with a singleton instance that is inherited by each unit test class in our tests project.

```
public class UnitTestsCommon
{
    public static IMapper AutoMapperInstance = null;

    public UnitTestsCommon()
    {
        if(UnitTestsCommon.AutoMapperInstance == null){       
            Mapper.Initialize(AutoMapperConfiguration.BootstrapMapperConfiguration);
            AutoMapperInstance = Mapper.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying to configure the Mapper at multiple places in your code, as I understand, you are trying to fix the issue by centralizing the configuration.

This issue could be resolved also through using the Instance API, where multiple (one per instance) configurations are possible (for plugin or more separated architectures)
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Static-and-Instance-API.html